# Run these two sections at once Python

Tags: python

I have some Python for a Raspberry Pi where I test for a button press (first loop) and use it to start and stop a timer (second loop). However, if I run this program only the first loop in the sequence runs. How can I make it so both run at the same time? Code:

EDIT: made changes to code in attempt to accommodate threading. Would this work?

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/Python')

import lcd
lcd.lcd_init()

import time

import threading
from threading import Thread

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

latest_state = None
status = False

seconds = 0
minutes = 0
hours = 0

def button():
    while True:
        if status == True:
            seconds +=1
        if seconds == 59:
            seconds = 0
            minutes = minutes + 1
        if minutes == 59:
            minutes = 0
            hours = hours + 1

        tup =  "  H:",hours," M:",minutes," S:",seconds

        display = ''.join(map(str, tup))

        lcd.lcd_string(display,2)

        time.sleep(0.99) 

Thread(target = button).start()

while True:
    inputValue = GPIO.input(23)
    if inputValue != latest_state:
        latest_state = inputValue
        if latest_state:
            print " "
        else:
            status = not status
            print status
            print " "
```

Comment: Research the `threading` module

Comment: I did, thank you. Had a go at it. Would this work? I edited the code in the question. @cricket_007

Comment: It should still pause at the first `while True:` loop. Try to put `Thread(target = button).start()` above it

Comment: Put the `while True;` block at the very end, after `Thread(...).start()` line.  Basically, you first define the `button()` function, then use it in `Thread(...).start()` line, and go into your `while True:` loop.

Comment: Like this? @Addison

Comment: Would what Addison suggested work? @cricket_007

Comment: You tell us :) Does it?

Comment: From looking at your `button()` code, it looks like it will exit and end the thread after `status` becomes `False`, which means your button will only work once.

Comment: Hmm... Not near my Pi right now. Ill try it out when I am. Thank you though! @cricket_007

Comment: Oops. That if loop is meant to be four spaces ahead. Thanks anyway. @Addison

Comment: You'll want to define your (hour, minute, second) outside the function, by the way

Comment: Stop indenting your `if`. It is not correct.

Comment: What? How so? @cricket_007

Comment: Just the `if` needs to be one the same indent as the previous. That's all

Comment: I think I fixed what you meant. @cricket_007

Comment: Btw, it might be easier to manipulate the time with [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects.

Comment: Ill have a look. Thank you @Addison

Comment: Really confused @cricket_007 - The program seems to be running perfectly fine on the Raspberry Pi, except at about 1/10 of the speed it should be running at. Seconds move up at a rate of about 1:10

Comment: `time.sleep(0.99)`... Are you sure that's correct?